# constexpr non-static members for classes. Are they really compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Consider a class with constexpr non static member function.

```
template <int k> class A { A() {} };
template <> class B : public A <k> {
    B() : A{} {}
    constexpr int foo() const { return k+42; } 
}
```

Is `foo()` really compile time with any object of B? What about constexpr members?

```
template <int k> class A { A() {} };
template <> class B : public A <k> {
    B() : A{} {}
    constexpr int foo_var = k+42;
}
```

Will accesses to foo_var be compile time substituted? Will B have foo_var in its object memory layout?

What about `std::array<T,N>::size()`??

Comment: Make all the constructors `constexpr` too. That being said, compile-time evaluation is not guaranteed, but if such is possible, it can be used in places where a compile-time constant is required.